# Would you allow your child to play tennis?

Tags: injury-prevention, children, tennis, elbows

Does anyone have any personal experiences or information related to "Tennis Elbow" or tennis related injuries. I'm looking for feedback relating to all age groups.

I've personally only seen overuse "wear and tear" injuries in adults has anyone ever seen this happen to any younger player?

In your opinion what age do you think is reasonable to allow my child to play tennis?  Any basic safety tips are appreciated.

Comment: Can someone explain why a question such as this would be closed?  I don't understand the danger providing information that allows parents to make informed decisions when they'd like their children to play sports.

Not only is the information cited from a credible source (that specializes in pediatrics), it is clearly stated to seek their doctors advice -- Even though general practitioners are not trained in-depth at treating musculoskeletal conditions -- Which is why these cases are referred.

Comment: This question was closed (Without moderator intervention) because it was not related to an ongoing fitness program. In the original form, it was just asking about prevalence of a diagnosis. The edit does attempt to bring it on topic, but it still is off topic as it is blatantly asking "What is your opinion", which is pretty much off topic on every SE site. Questions are expected to have answers, not just solicit opinions.

Answer (score 1):

According to *The Institute for Sports Medicine* **Children rarely get tennis elbow**. It is most common in adults, but can affect adolescents as well.

---

### What is it?

Tennis elbow, or lateral epicondylitis, is an overuse injury the tendons that originate at the outside of the elbow. Tendons are like ropes which connect the ends of muscles to bone. The tendons affected in tennis elbow attach the muscles of the forearm to the humerus (upper arm bone).

---

### Causes

Overuse of these forearm muscles causes fraying of the tendon. With tennis, the stress is greatest on the outer elbow of the dominant arm during a backhand swing. Incorrect grip size or swing mechanics can contribute to the injury.

---

### Symptoms

Your child may have pain in the elbow during or after activity without significant swelling or redness. The pain may travel down the forearm. Pain usually begins gradually without one specific injury to the joint. The pain may improve with rest, but often returns when the activity (such as tennis) is resumed. Some individuals notice decreased grip strength on the affected arm.

---

### Prevention

For young athletes, attention to proper technique and equipment can help prevent tennis elbow. If they've have had tennis elbow in the past, continuing with stretching and eccentric forearm strengthening may prevent return of this condition. Tight muscles put more stress on the attached tendons and bones, putting these tissues at risk for injury.

---

**Hopefully that helps.**

And as always, if you suspect your child has any signs or symptoms of tennis elbow please consult a medical professional.

---

***Source:*** 
https://luriechildrens.org/en-us/care-services/conditions-treatments/tennis-elbow/Pages/index.aspx